# Spitting an Array and wrapping it with an html tag - BC.Next (Liquid)

Tags: jquery, html, liquid, business-catalyst

Just a simple question over here for anyone who uses Business Catalyst, is there away to split array data from a web app (with liquid)? A perfect example would be when you create a check box field. When the data outputs, it is just a single string that looks like this "Ryan, Ashley, Melissa". Would I would like to do is split the data, and then wrap with a li.

I have created JQuery version of this which works, but I would love to see if there is away to perform this with liquid, as I am new to the platform.

```
$('.padt20').find('ul').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   var words = $this.text().split(",");
   var text = words.join("</li><li>");

     $this.html("<li>" + text + "</li>");
        });
```

HTML:

```
<ul>{{ArrayTag}}</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution to the problem! You need to assign an array then split it. You need to create a variable first as it won't work if you try to split it within the for loop.

```
{% assign array = ArrayTag | split: "," %}
{% for i in array -%}
 <li> {{ i }} </li>
{% endfor %}
```